# Would SQL Server Express be able to handle half TB worth of data?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

We have half TB of data in excel files. We are trying to decide which version of SQL Server will be needed. There are only two users that will be infrequently querying the database. We are curious do we need a SQL Server Standard or Enterprise? Or would Express version suffice. Assuming the database will be well thought out and well designed?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://support.symantec.com/en_US/article.TECH224181.html

```
SQL Server Express databases have strict size limits which can cause problems when CMDB grows. 

Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Express edition has a database size limit to 4GB
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Express edition has a database size limit to 4GB
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Express edition has a database size limit to 10GB
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Express edition has a database size limit to 10GB
Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Express edition has a database size limit to 10GB
```

Instead of SQL Server Express, get a Developer edition if you are only testing and not for production otherwise Standard should suffice.

Comment: Developer edition is only for testing and not production use.

Comment: Your answer didnt have it at first as I saw it on the page... also users querying the database counts as production usage. Developer edition is only for testing database functionality and app functionality against that.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful suggestions maSTAShuFu! I will take that rout for the development stage. How difficult is it to migrate to Standard edition once we are ready to go live? Are there articles, sites, books you suggest to read? Thanks.

Comment: generally the same apart from the licence and actual usage... migration should not be an issue

Comment: How about cost? It seems that there is only a one option, which is to purchase the database for a one time fee of $3,717. Do you know if there is a subscription based database?

Comment: try cloud storage could be cheaper

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There are plenty of SQL Server installations that are far bigger than a terabyte and it's one of the few relational databases with great single-machine scaling.

Express would not work as it's limited to a 10GB database size. Asd of 2016 SP1 and newer, all editions have the same features and are priced based on cores/resources used. For relatively little usage, you would do fine with the Standard edition and can use features like columnstore indexes to vastly improve storage and performance.

ALSO - what do you mean by excel files? Hopefully you're actually storing the data as relational data in sql tables, not as raw files...?

Comment: The data is currently stored in .txt files. Their size a is about 500 GB. We are in the process of migrating it into a sql server. I am curious, how much it costs for a Standard edition? Is it a one time fee or is it a subscription base?

Comment: You can buy licenses for the software once and run it for as long as you want, although support for that version ends after a certain number of years. Pricing for Standard is around 4k at the lowest core count.

Comment: If you're really only querying the data a few times per year, you can also use another database like PostgreSQL, MySQL or MariaDB which are free and open-source. They provide similar functionality. SQL Server 2017 (which is still in beta) also runs on Linux if you want to save money on Windows licenses.